# Rails 4.2 fragment caching isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memcached, dalli, fragment-caching

I'm trying to fragment cache a static portion of my site, but it doesn't seem to be working at all. I've set up `config/application.rb` with the following:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.cache_store = :dalli_store
```

In my view, I have this:

```
<% cache 'cache_key' do %>
  <!-- cached markup -->
<% end %>
```

I don't see anything in my logs about saving the fragment to cache or retrieving it on subsequent page loads. I've also tried using the default Rails `:file_store` caching. I know that the cache store is working because using `Rails.cache.fetch` works properly.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 6):

In Rails 5:

```
$ rails dev:cache
Development mode is now being cached.
```

Activates caching in development environment.

Comment: Since this question is about Rails 4.2, you may want to leave this as a comment instead.. (Also, it's not really clear what your code is supposed to do in the context of this question)

Answer (score 4):

You are probably working in your development environment.
in /config/environments/development change:

> # Show full error reports and disable caching.
>   config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
>   config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

TO

> # Show full error reports and disable caching.
>   config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
>   config.action_controller.perform_caching = **true**

The development settings might override the other settings.
Make sure memcache is installed and running. If there is something wrong it should show up in the console.